# How do I empty all registers in vim?

Tags: vim, copy-paste

How can I delete the values associated with all the registers in vim?

I found [this snippet](http://kba49.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/clear-all-registers-and-macros-in-vim/) on the web:

```
function! ClearRegisters()
    let regs='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789/-="*+'
    let i=0
    while (i<strlen(regs))
        exec 'let @'.regs[i].'=""'
        let i=i+1
    endwhile
endfunction

command! ClearRegisters call ClearRegisters()
```

It almost works, but it puts an empty value into each register, rather than deleting the register. Crucially, that means that when you then use the `:registers` command, all the registers are still present, which makes the display cumbersome (although it's worth noting that if you quit vim, and reload it, the registers are then fully emptied, even if `viminfo` is set up to save them).

How can I **fully** delete all the registers, so that `:registers` doesn't display them, and without needing a restart?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do this

Comment: Why exactly do you want to hide those registers?

Comment: related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/467/how-can-i-clear-a-register-multiple-registers-completely

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike marks, which have a `:delmarks` command and a special "not set" value, registers cannot be deleted. An empty register is the closest to an "unused" state you can get. (However, Vim and the `:registers` command do have the special behavior you've observed where uninitialized registers that have not been restored from the *viminfo* file are skipped in the output.)

I think what you're rather after is an extended `:Registers` custom command (you can even alias that to the lowercase original command with a `:cmap` or the *cmdalias* plugin) which omits empty registers from its output, like this:

```
function! s:Registers( arguments )
    redir => l:registersOutput
        silent! execute 'registers' a:arguments
    redir END
    for l:line in split(l:registersOutput, "\n")
        if l:line !~# '^"\S\s*$'
            echo l:line
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
command! -nargs=? Registers call <SID>Registers(<q-args>)
```

---

Alternatively, you could write a Vim patch to introduce a `:delregisters` command. It should not be too difficult to write; it basically has to set the `y_regs[i].y_array` structure to `NULL` (see `ops.c` in the Vim source code).

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your `.vimrc`:

```
command! WipeReg for i in range(34,122) | silent! call setreg(nr2char(i), []) | endfor
```

and clear every register with `:WipeReg`

If you would like that to happen every time you start Vim also add:

```
autocmd VimEnter * WipeReg
```